# Where is t4 templates for subsonic 2.2?

Tags: subsonic

I've downloaded subsonic 2.2 source code,and i can't found the t4 templates in all projects
Anyone can tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are here:
http://subsonicproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SubSonic.Tests/Generated/T4
This looks like some sort of back port of the T4 ideas in v3. For active record.

Comment: Thanks,P a u l.
It looks looks incomplete

Answer (score 2):

SubSonic 2.2 doesn't use t4 templates, version 3 does. You can get the source from:

http://code.google.com/p/subsonicthree/source/checkout